# Caching in Java Code

Tags: java, hashmap, javac

In my code, I am using several file reading using [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). I am also using JAVA's in built [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Those causes several page-faults. Is there any in-built library which cares the caching mechanism and easily embed in Java code ?

Edit: I am using JAVAC.

Comment: What do you want to cache? Is it the entire file contents?

Comment: @devsundar, Actually I want a library/code that cares my codes caching and reduce the page faults.

Comment: You are aware that there is nothing wrong in itself with page faults?    Perhaps you should describe exactly what you see - perhaps even with screen dumps - and why you do not think it is a good idea?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, No there is nothing with page faults. I just want to reduce them to improve performance. Specifically, want to use more L1 & L2.

Comment: If you do file access the disk will be your bottleneck, not the cpu.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, Not only disk. HashMap also, which is memory resident.

Comment: @Arpssss use jvisualvm in the JDK to attach to your program and profile it.  You can then see where the time is actually spent by your program.  If you want to improve the performance, these areas are where you must focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Those causes several page-faults. 
>   They could do except the JVM usually places all the objects built at the same time or referenced in one place together so you might only have one one page fault.
>
> Is there any in-built library which cares the caching mechanism and easily embed in Java code ?

No, This is not simple to do in JAva, or any language unless the language is designed to make use of this from the start.

Fortunately its not something you usually have to worry about as most of your data is likely to be in cache if not main memory (you only get a page fault if the data is not in memory, e.g. on disk)

You can get page faults when reading a file from disk for the first time.  It is the job of the OS to ensure your access pattern is dealt with efficiently. If it is not, the best thing to do is a) use a faster drive like an SSD or b) use a different OS. (Unlikely to help)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is a JSR for caching. This is [JSR 107](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107) 
Looks like this is going to be a part of Java EE 7. 
In your case, I would recommend using one of the caching frameworks, some of them implement JSR 107 . 
 Maybe to keep your code supporting Java stands you should choose a caching framework that supports this JSR.  
However, you should consider if this does not hurt your flows/use-cases. 
You can get more details in [this](http://gregluck.com/blog/archives/2011/10/javax-cache-the-new-java-caching-standard/) blog.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention I am using JAVAC.